# Using the agent's methods on events

Tags: events, anylogic

Im using anylogic in order to build a model of randomly moving cars.
In that model i want to gather some information on the agents (Cars) using a varivable and an event block.

On the model i want the *event* to set the variable *carsLane* with the lane of the car that is currently on the road and to do so every 2 seconds.

The thing is that every time the event is suppose to take place i get "**NullpointerException**" error and it happen so on every method of *Car* that im trying to use using the Event.

The event is on the Main tab and the code im using on the action box:
`carsLane=Car.getLaneIndex();`

[On the image you can see the formation of the blocks and the code on the event's action box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1t71.jpg)

Am i using the *event* wrong or is it something else?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

This will be confusing to you, but the Agent Car that you defined in the model is NOT or does not contain the agents that are created in the carSource module, so doing carLane=Car.anything will give you an error, since the Car agent is probably empty or is not in any Lane.

To solve this, you need to do a bunch of things (and I will assume that you generate cars in your carsource in a way that there will be a maximum of 1 car in the road... if there are more, you have to do something different.

First: create a new Car agent with a population of cars, let's call it thecar (use the agent from the agent palette... not the "car type") with an initial population of 0.

[image: your car agent]

This agent will be an extension of the Car type you created:

[image: extends Car agent]

Second: In the car source, add your cars to a custom population:

[image: car population]
And also, your car source will generate cars of the type thecar:

[image: generate theCar]

third: In your event now you can do:
carsLane=thecars.get(0).getLaneIndex();

And I created the model for you... find it here:
https://ufile.io/5jkqu

Comment: Actually i do need more than 1 car at a time.                                              My desired project is to create a model that will always check, for any car that is currently on the road, if there is another car in the second lane and return true if so. Is there something different i need to do in order for the event to apply the condition on every car that is driving on the road?         -In addition, is it possible you will shed some more light on why, in my first model, the agent Car does not contain the agents that are created in the carSource?

Comment: in that case instead of thecars.get(0).getLaneIndex()

you do:
for(Thecar c : thecars){
c.getLaneIndex();
}